# Use a variable from a Class function into an other function

Tags: python, class, variables

As a new user of Python, I try to code a program to learn how to use class. This is what I got so far in my Game class

```
class Game(Table):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(21, 10)
        self.reset()


    def __str__(self):
        return makeGrid(self)

    def reset(self):
        self.setValues(' ' for _ in range(210))
        for v in range(10):
            self[10, v]='+'
    def Startup(self):
        p1=input('Player 1 name: ')
        p2=input('Player 2 name: ')


    def p1turn(self):
        print('r%, its your turn!'% p1)
```

My problem is that I want to use the p1 and p2 variables in some other function, but I realised that I can't access to a variable in a function and use it in an other function. ( In this case, if I try to run my p1turn(), I got an error because p1 does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In each function, the first reference passed in (conventionally bound to the name `self`) is a reference to the instance object of this class. One may store values as attributes of that instance.

Practically speaking, put `self.` in front of any variables that you want to share between methods, like so:

```
def Startup(self):
    self.p1=input('Player 1 name: ')
    self.p2=input('Player 2 name: ')


def p1turn(self):
    print('r%, its your turn!'% self.p1)
```

Comment: I tried, but I still get an error: Game has no attribute p1